# How to use comparison lemma to solve the differential inequality $\dot{h}\geq \frac{\gamma(h+h^2)}{\log(\frac{h}{1+h})}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, inequality

I am reading a paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7782377: (p.3864 top)
**Control Barrier Function Based Quadratic Programs for Safety Critical Systems**

The **comparison Lemma** says:

> Consider the scalar differential equation $$\dot{u} = f(t,u), \ \ \  u(t_0)=u_0,$$ where $f(t,u)$ is continuous in $t$ and locally Lipschitz in $u$, for all $t \geq 0$ and all $u\in J \subset \mathbb{R}$. Let $[t_0,T]$ be the interval of existence of the solution $u(t)$. Let $v(t)$ be a differentiable function  whose derivative $Dv(t)$ satisfies the differential inequality $$Dv(t) \leq f(t, v(t)), \ \ \ \ v(t_0) \leq u_0$$ with $v(t)\in J$ for all $t\in [t_0,T)$. Then, $v(t)\leq u(t)$ for all $t\in[t_0,T)$.

So suppose we have $$\dot{h}\geq \frac{\gamma(h+h^2)}{\log(\frac{h}{1+h})},$$ compared to the Lemma, we have $$Dv(t)=\frac{\gamma(h+h^2)}{\log(\frac{h}{1+h})},$$ how to obtain the result

$$h(x(t,x_0))\geq \frac{1}{-1+\exp\bigg(\sqrt{2\gamma t + \log^2\Big(\frac{h(x_0)+1}{h(x_0)}\Big)}\bigg)}?$$

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... What do you mean by $Dv(t)$? Is it just the time derivative (therefore the same as $\dot{v}$)?

Comment: @Cleopatra Yes!

Comment: Ok, and what is $x(t,x_0)$? Do you mean by $\dot{h}$ just the derivative of $h$ or $\frac{d}{dt}h(x(t,x_0))$? Normally you would solve the equation $v'(t)=\frac{\gamma(v+v^2)}{\log(\frac{v}{1+v})}$ and have $h(t)$ greater than the solution. However, here it fails and I suppose it's because we need some information about $x(t,x_0)$. I don't have acces to the paper you linked, so I cannot compare what they did

Comment: @Cleopatra $x(t,x_0)$ means $x(t)$ with initial condition $x_0$.  The following is the link accessible: https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06408  (p.3 bottom)